# sql error on search function

Tags: php, sql

In forehand i want to apologize that the variable names are dutch, but i am experiencing difficulties with my page navigation and search box...

this is the code:

```
$zoekwoord="";
$html.=<<<EOT
    <form method="get" class="zoek">
        <input type="hidden" name="page" value="home_overzicht">
        <input type="text" name="zoekwoord">
        <input type="submit" value="zoeken"/>
    </form>
EOT;
if(!empty($_GET['zoekwoord'])){
        $zoekwoord=$_GET['zoekwoord'];
    }

    $itemsperpagina = 20;
    $aantal=$data->berichten_tellen($zoekwoord);
    $aantalpaginas=ceil($aantal / $itemsperpagina); // Altijd omhoog!

    if (empty($_GET['pagina'])) {
        $pagina=1;
    } else {
        $pagina=intval($_GET['pagina']);
    }

    if (($pagina<1) || ($pagina>$aantalpaginas)) $pagina=1; 

    $html_navigatie='<p>';
    if ($pagina>1) {
        $html_navigatie.='<a href="?page=home_overzicht&pagina='.($pagina-1).'&zoekwoord='.($zoekwoord).'">Vorige</a>';
    }
    $html_navigatie.=" Pagina {$pagina}/{$aantalpaginas} ";
    if ($pagina<$aantalpaginas) {
        $html_navigatie.='<a href="?page=home_overzicht&pagina='.($pagina+1).'&zoekwoord='.($zoekwoord).'">Volgende</a>';
    }
    $html_navigatie.="</p>";

    $html.=$html_navigatie;
```

this is the function to count the messages

```
function berichten_tellen($zoekwoord=""){

        $result = $this->mysqli->query(
<<<EOT
        SELECT COUNT (*) FROM home
        WHERE lower(concat_ws(' ',kop,auteur))
        LIKE lower('%{$zoekwoord}%')
EOT
        );
        if(!$result){
            die("MySQL error: " . $this->mysqli->error);
        }
        if($result){
            $row = $result->fetch_row();
            $result->free();
            return($row[0]);
        }else{
            return(FALSE);
        }

    }
```

here is the function for the navigation

```
function home_berichten_laten_zien($pagina, $itemsperpagina,$zoekwoord=""){

            $l = ($pagina-1) * $itemsperpagina;
            if ($l<0) $l=0;

            $result = $this->mysqli->query(
<<<EOT
            SELECT id, kop, artikel, auteur, datum, status
            FROM home
            WHERE lower(concat_ws(' ',kop,auteur))
            LIKE lower('%{$cleandata}%') ORDER BY kop LIMIT {$l},{$itemsperpagina}  
EOT
            );
            if(!$result){
                die("MySQL error: " . $this->mysqli->error);
            }
            $waardes = array();
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                $waardes[] = $row;
            }
            return $waardes;
        }
```

and this is the error i get as soon as i am opening the specific page :

MySQL error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*) FROM home WHERE lower(concat_ws(' ',kop,auteur)) LIKE lower('%%')' at line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buried deep in the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/function-resolution.html) is this:

> To use the name as a function call in an expression, there must be no
>   whitespace between the name and the following “(” parenthesis
>   character.

That is, `COUNT(*)` is recognized.  But, `COUNT (*)` is not.

Note this is a peculiarity of the MySQL database.

Answer (score 1):

The COUNT (*) you have is incorrect. You are not permitted to put count (*), you must put it like count(*). I think there's something you can do if you insist on putting count (*), but I am not sure. Look it up [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ignore_space).